# I used Appium to connect to the mobile app, but the permission error occurred

Tags: appium, appium-android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4hsi.png)

How do you troubleshoot these problems

Comment: Please be more specific and formulate an actual self-contained question.

Comment: @Codor : you should check image.

Comment: @T.Che Honestly. The prompt "enter image description here" addresses the author of the question to come up with a suitable name for the image.

Comment: @Codor : he is new, he will learn.

Answer (score 2):

This was the solution that helped me:

- enable USB debugging, in USB debugging (Security settings) Install
- via   USB options in the device you are using.

please check [here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/40896/permissions-error-trying-to-run-appium-test-on-android)